# What is the female equivalent of the name "Abdullah"?

Tags: naming

Abdullah is a pretty common for Muslim males which means 'Servant of Allah'.

I'd like to know the female equivalent of it as I have not come across any females with a similar nomenclature.

Comment: Amatullah I believe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Arabic equivalent of

> 'Abdullah
>    عبد الله

is

> Amatullah
>    أمة الله

Because the feminine of

> ' Abd
>   عبد

Is

> Amah
>   أمة

Other synonyms are:

> جاريَة  Jariah.
>   خادِمَة Khadimah.
>   عَبْدَة   Abdah'.
>   مَمْلُوكَة. Mamlukah

I must say that I have hardly heard of anybody naming his daughter Amatullah, but heard of a convert who gave herself this name.
Basically equivalent to all the names that include one of Allah's names for men their female forms are allowed for female names like Amatullah,

> Amatu-Rahman
>   أمة الرحمان/الرحمن،
>   Amatu-ar-Razaq
>   أمة الرزاق.
>   etc.

according to this fatwa on [islamweb](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/110158/) (in Arabic). However they recommend when calling a person not to call her (briefly) Amah. But this is just a recommendation not a prohibition to do so.

Answer (score 1):

There are some, like

عبيدة 
or

عبيدة الله
or more rarely, in Morocco there are women called

عوبيدة
There's a feminine for sure

Comment: 'Obaydah عبيدة is a diminutive of ' Abdah عبدة.

Comment: In Morocco it's used, but I think that it is more of a Moroccan nuance thing, rather than a pejorative term